# Algorithm: How to launch same code with different parameters?

Tags: algorithm

I have a script **A** to run a block of code **B** on 2 machines: **X** and **Y**.

In the script **A**, I have a variable called **option**:

If user chooses to deploy on machine **X**, option=1

If user chooses to deploy on machine **Y**, option=2

If user chooses to deploy on **X** and **Y**, option=3

Now the problem is, the code block **B** just has two parameters that depend on **X** or **Y**.

So if option = 3, I do not want to copy two times of this block, it's a waste of space and not good algorithm.

At the moment the pseudo-code looks like this:

```
//parameter a,b,c depends on machine X or Y
option=get_user_option()
if(option==1)
  {B(a(X),b(X),c(X))}
if(option==2)
  {B(a(Y),b(Y),c(Y))}
if(option==3)
  {
   B(a(X),b(X),c(X))
   B(a(Y),b(Y),c(Y))
}
```

What should I do to make the algorithm simple?

Thanks.

Comment: which (script-)language are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows batch

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be changed like this:

```
  //parameter a,b,c depends on machine X or Y
  option=get_user_option()
  if(option==1 Or option==3)
    {B(a(X),b(X),c(X))}
  if(option==2 Or option==3)
    {B(a(Y),b(Y),c(Y))}
```

so for option=3 both code will execute